# subfolder htaccess file not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site called "`http://www.example.com`", it has a htaccess file.

And I have a subfolder called "`http://www.example.com/sub/`", it has a htaccess to convert `.php` to `.html` page extension, but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

What can I do for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive.

First make sure that the `mod_rewrite` module is activated from your `httpd.conf` file.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then put the following `.htaccess` file into the `sub/` folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```